# Can a ruby mixin access variables that exist in the class it's mixed into?

Tags: ruby

I muddling my way through a tic-tac-toe game on the terminal, and I've made a board structure and decide to create a mixin that contains the win conditions.

My mixin has this block of code:

```
##check if 3 in a diagonal was made
    diagonal_win = [[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
    ##Deconstruction
    diagonal_win.each_index do |item|
      d_counter = 0
      diagonal_win.each_index do |an_item|
        x,y = COORDINATES[diagonal_win[item][an_item]]
        if @structure[x][y] == 'X'
          d_counter += 1
        end #end of if block
      end #an_item end
```

wherein the COORDINATES hash refers to the constant within the class I use the mixin like so:

```
class Board
  include WinCondition
  COORDINATES = {
    1 => [0,0],
    2 => [0,1],
    3 => [0,2],
    4 => [1,0],
    5 => [1,1],
    6 => [1,2],
    7 => [2,0],
    8 => [2,1],
    9 => [2,2]
  }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I know I can just introduce the COORDINATES variable into the mixin,but I want to know if you really can't access constants in a class via mixin, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Does your mixin really only have these lines of code – no module name or method definition? How do you run your example? _doesn't seem to work_ is a bit vague. What does not work? Is there an error message, what does it say? Or is there just an unexpected output?

Comment: Oh, my bad! My mixin is a module named WinCondition, the same one in the include line. When I run the file with the Board class, it says COORDINATES in the context of the mixin does not exist. The first block of code exists in function_A, and I'm testing if it works by doing sample = Board.new then sample.function_A()

Comment: Could you edit that information into your question, please?

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Did you try to define you constant before including the mixin?

Answer (score 1):

No, because `COORDINATES` in `WinCondition` refers to `WinCondition::COORDINATES`. Here's a simple example.

```
module WinCondition
  def show_coordinates
    p COORDINATES
  end
end

class Board
  include WinCondition

  COORDINATES = {
    1 => [0, 0],
    2 => [0, 1],
    3 => [0, 2],
    4 => [1, 0],
    5 => [1, 1],
    6 => [1, 2],
    7 => [2, 0],
    8 => [2, 1],
    9 => [2, 2]
  }.freeze
end

Board.new.show_coordinates

test.rb:3:in `show_coordinates': uninitialized constant WinCondition::COORDINATES (NameError)
```

Instead, use a class method.

```
module WinCondition
  def show_coordinates
    p self.class.coordinates
  end
end

class Board
  include WinCondition

  COORDINATES = {
    1 => [0, 0],
    2 => [0, 1],
    3 => [0, 2],
    4 => [1, 0],
    5 => [1, 1],
    6 => [1, 2],
    7 => [2, 0],
    8 => [2, 1],
    9 => [2, 2]
  }.freeze
  
  def self.coordinates
    COORDINATES
  end
end

Board.new.show_coordinates
```

Using a class methods to access data, even ones which just wrap a constant, have some advantages.

- It allows subclasses to override `.coordinates`. Constants cannot be overridden.
- It allows subclasses and users of `WinCondition` to decide how to implement `.coordiantes`. They're not restricted to a constant.

For example.

```
class DynamicBoard < Board
  def self.coordinates
    # maybe load them from a file or something
  end
end
```